# How to internalize the extension operator of a monad in a Cartesian closed category?

Tags: category-theory, monads, cartesian-closed-categories

Let $\mathbb C$ be a Cartesian closed category and $(T, \eta, \mu)$ be a monad on $\mathbb C$.

The extension operator $\_^{\sharp} : Hom(X, TY) → Hom(TX, TY)$ is defined by:
$$f^{\sharp} = \mu_{Y}\circ Tf$$
Is it possible to define a morphism in $\mathbb C$ of type $(T Y)^X \to (T Y)^{T X}$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not always possible to define such a morphism.

Regard the 4-element Boolean algebra $\{ \emptyset, \{0\}, \{1\}, \{0,1\} \}$, ordered by subset inclusion, as a poset category $\mathbb{B}_4$. This category is Cartesian closed, with product given by intersection, and exponential $X^Y$ given by $(\{0,1\}\setminus X) \cup Y$.

Consider the endofunctor $T: \mathbb{B}_4 \rightarrow \mathbb{B}_4$ which sends the empty set to itself, and sends every nonempty set to $\{0,1\}$. We have $X \subseteq TX$ and $TTX \subseteq TX$ for any object $X$ of $\mathbb{B}_4$. The required naturality squares trivially commute, so $T$ induces a monad on $\mathbb{B}_4$.

Let $X=\{0\}$ and $Y=\emptyset$. Then $(TY)^X = \{1\} \cup \emptyset = \{1\}$, while $(TY)^{TX} = \emptyset \cup \emptyset = \emptyset$, and there is no morphism from $\{1\}$ to $\emptyset$ in $\mathbb{B}_4$.

Comment: Strictly speaking, you replied my question (I now regret the way I formulated it). But what I would really like to know is what do I need to assume about $\mathbb C$ in order for such morphism to be definable?

Comment: That's an interesting (and very different) question: I doubt there's much you can assume about $\mathbb{C}$ itself to make this hold for all functors $T$. It can fail for arbitrary $T$ even over very well-behaved categories $\mathbb{C}$, such as a topos. It holds for $\mathrm{Set}$ itself of course, but for essentially meta-theoretic reasons (I kinda doubt it even holds for categories elementarily equivalent to $\mathrm{Set}$, which would rule out any category-theoretic characterization). And it wouldn't hold for nice things such as $\mathrm{Hask}$, even if $\mathrm{Hask}$ was a category.

Comment: Note also that while the category $\mathbb{B}_2$ has the desired property, $\mathbb{B}_4 \cong \mathbb{B}_2 \times \mathbb{B}_2$ does not. While this is not surprising, it is telling: it means that the strict theory of categories with your property can't be essentially algebraic, unlike the theory of strict CCCs.